# android UI design using eclipse

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to navigate to a new activity using Intent. My code is as follows:

```
Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.deviceinit);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ANDROIDPORTINGActivity.this,Central.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
})
```

i have created a new class `Central`. But on click of the button i get an error message of FORCED CLOSED! Any suggestions for navigation into a different activity?

Comment: Please post stacktrace from your logcat

Comment: remove this from Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.deviceinit);

Comment: @NikhilLamba - Why? Including `this` is a matter of personal preference, and probably has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Central should be an activity too, and in `AndroidManifest.xml` add

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Central">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've included the `Central` activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

More information about app manifests: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html